# how to identify an object from the generated point cloud?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

point cloud and ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11436/how-to-identify-an-object-from-the-generated-point-cloud?/) by [manns](https://answers.ros.org/users/1176/manns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I had a few shots with VFH features recognitiom which work only on 3d information.
Check these pcl tutorials:

[How 3D Features work in PCL](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/how_features_work.php#how-3d-features-work)

[Estimating VFH signatures for a set of points](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_estimation.php#vfh-estimation)

[Cluster Recognition and 6DOF Pose Estimation using VFH descriptors](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_recognition.php#vfh-recognition)

It kind of gives good results, provided that you took enough snapshots from enough viewpoints of your objects during the learning phase.

I noticed that someone pushed it a level farther, by learning objects directly from 3d models and clustering the observed point clouds.

This work is advertised in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYP6Ys7nxds) and hosted in the ROS package[vfh_recognition](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vfh_recognition).

As other said, object recognition stays a hard problem.

I hope it helps

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1